# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> D:\Compressed\namazcopy\build\location\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11:9-15:56: AAPT: error: attribute android:foregroundServiceType not found.
> [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCzVL.png) [pubspec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLR1u.png) [flutter doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAQW1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your xml file

```
  <manifest>
  ...
  <service ... 
 androidd:foregroundServiceType="location|camera" />
 </manifest>
```

If still this does not work go through this documents surely you will  find solution
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#java